# Python Simple SSL Socket Server

Tags: python, openssl

Just trying to set up a simple SSL server. I have never had anything SSL work for me in the past. I have a loose understanding of how SSL certificates and signing.

The code is simple

```
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="mycertfile") ###############

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('', 2099))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    sslsoc = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
    request = sslsoc.read()
    print(request)
```

The line in there with the ###s after it is the one that isnt working. I don't know what I have to do with openssl to generate a PEM file that will work here.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how to make this simple socket work.

By the way, this is NOT used for HTTP.

Comment: If you're amenable to using twisted, there's a good example here that uses OpenSSL: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html

Looks like that requires a certificate and a public key, where the certificate is signed with the public key's private pair.

Comment: That's good and it looks rather simpler, but all I need are the commands to generate the correct file to use. I tried it a little while ago but got very strange errors. Oviously I didn't sign it correctly or use the right file.

Comment: It looks like there are a lot of tutorials for this, have you tried following this one, for example? http://devsec.org/info/ssl-cert.html

Comment: try: `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 7 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycertfile.pem -out mycertfile.pem` (google 'create self-signed test certificate')

Comment: Okay, It seems like I was doing it semi right already. The big problem was that I was only giving python the signed certificate. I needed to give it the private key, which makes sense in hindsight.

Comment: In the future when posting to SO, please don't just say "it's not working", if there is an exception, error messages or anything else diagnostic printed out, then include that in the question. Verbatim, so copy-and-paste, do _not_ edit the information. It will help a lot getting correct answers. Also, as you found the problem then you should post that as an answer and accept it. It will help future visitors to find it more easily.

Answer (score 30):

you can use this command to generate a self-signed certificate

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout cert.pem
```

the openssl framework will ask you to enter some information, such as your country, city, etc. just follow the instruction, and you will get a `cert.pem` file. the output file will have both your RSA private key, with which you can generate your public key, and the certificate.
the output file looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 # your private key
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 # your certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

just load it, and the ssl module will handle the rest for you:

```
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert.pem", keyfile="cert.pem")
```

btw, there is **no** "SSLContext" in python2. for guys who are using python2, just assign the pem file when wrapping socket:

```
newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                             server_side=True,
                             certfile="cert.pem",
                             keyfile="cert.pem",
                             ssl_version=YOUR CHOICE)
```

available ssl version: `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1`, `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv2`, `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3`, `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23`. if you have no idea, `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23` may be your choice as it provides the most compatibility with other versions.

Comment: to create `context`, call `ssl.create_default_context` function (it works on the recent Python 2 versions too).

Comment: I know this is an old post, but due to the POODLE vulnerability no-one should be advising the use of SSLv3 over TLS. More information at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you provide a `certfile`, but no `keyfile`. Both are required.

Comment: You note is ok but you should say in comments.